# servlet request.getParameter cannot be resolved

Tags: java, servlets

The following is a servlet for getting parameter from a jsp page.

I am trying to run following code --

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class oneServlet extends HttpServlet {

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

    String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.1.11.112:5432/pack";
    String username = "pack";
    String password = "pack";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String user=request.getParameter("t1");
    String pass=request.getParameter("t2");
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        String queryTest = "select username,password from login";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryTest);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
         String username=rs.getString(1);
         String password=rs.getString(2);    

   if(user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password))
       {

     JFrame frame = new JFrame("/LoginSuccess.jsp");

       }    
        else
        {

            System.out.println("Login Failed,Please try Againe");
        }
        }}

     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

}

It's showing error in request.getParameter that " request cannot be resolved. Can anyone help me resolve this.

Comment: Start learning about serlvets in [our Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extends `HttpServlet`, you need to override `doGet` and `doPost()` which take `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` as parameters.

Example:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
  .......
       String user=request.getParameter("t1"); //Use request variable to do get...
}
```

Read more [here](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServletExamples.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html)

Comment: And move the code of `main` method to `doPost` method. `doGet` is generally used for pre-processing a request.

Comment: @RohitJain `doGet` will be executed only if access to the servlet mapping of the servlet directly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Not exactly. You can also access `doGet` from a `form`, using the `method = GET`, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: @RohitJain I know that, but that's not pre-processing.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Yeah, that is why I wrote there, it's a bad idea, because it's not what doGet is used for. I just wrote that, because you said, `executed only if`.

Comment: @RohitJain yeah, my mistake for not writing the whole idea there =\ but you're correct. I assumed the GET request in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets doesnt have main() , they are executed by SelvletContainer or Webserver (like tomcat)

In your scenario.

```
public void doGet(){
    String user=request.getParameter("t1");
    String pass=request.getParameter("t2");
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        String queryTest = "select username,password from login";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryTest);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
         String username=rs.getString(1);
         String password=rs.getString(2);    


       if(user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password))
           {
     //JFrame frame = new JFrame("/LoginSuccess.jsp");
     request.getRequestDispatcher().redirect("/LoginSuccess.jsp");

       }    
        else
        {

            System.out.println("Login Failed,Please try Againe");//This will print at the console
        }
        }}

     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

Learn more about [servlets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/index.htm)